# How to download multiple files in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, blob

Hi I am working in react with typescript. I am trying to download multiple files one after the other. Below is my sample code.

```
const blockBlobURL = BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL,reportPath);
const blockWindBlobURL = BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL,windReportPath);
const blocktopographyBlobURL = BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL,topoGraphyPath);
this.FileArr.push(blockBlobURL, blockWindBlobURL, blocktopographyBlobURL);

var link = document.createElement('a');
link.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(link);

for (var i = 0; i < this.FileArr.length; i++) {
  link.setAttribute('href', this.FileArr[i].url);
  link.click();
}

document.body.removeChild(link);
```

In the above code I have three files and I put it inside array. I am looping and trying to download three files one after the another. My above code is able to download only one file but not remaining two files.
I have put for loop and looping but only first file its able to download and remaining two I am not able to download. Can someone help me  what I am doing wrong in the above code. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you